# Knapsack problem: choose 5 elements among 100, weight <= 100, maximise total value

Tags: algorithm, google-sheets, knapsack-problem

I have a data table containing n=100 elements :

| Element | weight | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 24 | 80 |
| B | 43 | 77 |
| C | 51 | 72 |
| D | 38 | 70 |
| E | 27 | 65 |
| F | 7 | 58 |
| .. | .. | .. |

And I would like to create an algorithm to get 5 elements where :

- sum of the 5 weights is capped to 100
- sum of the 5 values should be the maximum possible

I'm on google sheet but I don't know how to do it properly.

I tried to iterate on every element but it was not really effective...

Comment: How many elements do you have total?

Comment: This problem is called the knapsack problem; data1 is the weight, data2 is the value.

Comment: @Stef I have about 100 elements

Comment: You can get a dynamic programming solution by calling T(n, k, w) the highest sum that you can get by selecting exactly k items, with total weight under w, and selecting only items up to item n. Using the fact that solutions for T(n,k,w) either don't use the nth item or use the nth item, you get the recurrence formula: T(n, k, w) = max(T(n-1, k, w), value(n) + T(n-1, k-1, w-weight(n)))

Comment: While stef solution is undoubtebly much faster, better and prettier,  100 choose 5 is only ~75 million so you can simply bruteforce  it also.

Comment: This is a [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). The problem is known to be [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness) or harder, and there is no _simple_ formula to solve the optimization problem you ask. That is not to say that in the scenario you present there would not be a way to get a good enough result reasonably fast. See [Knapsack_problem/Solving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Solving) for possible approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar enough with google sheets, but here is a simple recursive function with memoization in python, using the following recurrence formula:

```
if weight(n) <= w:
    T(n, k, w) = max(
                     T(n-1, k, w),
                     value(n) + T(n-1, k-1, w-weight(n))
                 )
else:
    T(n, k, w) = T(n-1, k, w)
```

where

- T(n, k, w) is the maximum sum of `k` values whose weights sum up to at most `w`, using only items up to the `n`th item
- T(100, 5, 100) is the overall solution to your problem
- if the best solution for (n, k, w) doesn't use the nth item, then it's equal to the best solution for (n-1, k, w)
- if the best solution for (n, k, w) uses the nth item, then it's equal to the the value of the nth item plus the value of the best solution for (n-1, k-1, w-weight(n))

In python:

```py
import numpy as np

n_items_total, k_items_solution, max_weight = 100, 5, 100

data = np.random.randint(0, max_weight+1, (n_items_total,2)))

def knapsack(n, k, w):
    if (n, k, w) not in knapsack.t:
        if w < 0 or n < 0 or k < 0:
            knapsack.t[(n, k, w)] = -1000  # big negative number, large enough that solution is invalid
        elif n < k:
            knapsack.t[(n, k, w)] = -1000 # presuming you want exactly k items; remove this line if <= k is okay
        elif k == 0:
            knapsack.t[(n, k, w)] = 0
        else:
            knapsack.t[(n, k, w)] = max(knapsack(n-1, k, w), data[n-1, 0] + knapsack(n-1, k-1, w-data[n-1,1]))
    return knapsack.t[(n, k, w)]
knapsack.t = {}

def traceback_solution(t, n, k, w):
    if k <= 0:
        return
    s = t[(n, k, w)]
    a = t[(n-1, k, w)]
    b = data[n-1, 0] + t[(n-1, k-1, w-data[n-1, 1])]
    if s == a:
        yield from traceback_solution(t, n-1, k, w)
    elif s == b:
        yield (n-1, data[n-1])
        yield from traceback_solution(t, n-1, k-1, w-data[n-1, 1])
    else:
        raise Error

best_score = knapsack(n_items_total, k_items_solution, max_weight)
solution = list(traceback_solution(knapsack.t, n_items_total, k_items_solution, max_weight))

print(solution)
# [(87, array([97,  2])),
#  (84, array([97, 29])), 
#  (63, array([98, 11])), 
#  (36, array([98, 32])), 
#  (0, array([99,  6]))]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !
I'll try that in google script

Comment: @gnozer44 Note my algorithm has two parts. First part is in function `knapsack`, which calculates T(100, 5, 100) and fills a dictionary with intermediate values of T(n, k, w). Function `knapsack` only calculates the values of T(n, k, w), it doesn't tell you directly which k elements were chosen to arrive at these solutions. Then function `traceback` traces back through the T(n, k, w) array to determine which elements were used: if `s == b`, then element n-1 was used, and if `s == a`, then element n-1 was not used.

Comment: I begin in python and I would like to make it work on my sample just to see how it works but not with random numbers. I tried to define data with arrays in an array but i get errors https://trinket.io/python3/d4608dcd58 (data var commented)
Also, is it possible to set values as floats ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: @gnozer44 If you had an excel file, you should be able to export it as csv, and then read this csv into an array with [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html)

Comment: @gnozer44 Otherwise if you wanted to "hardcode" the data in the python file like you did, the correct syntax would be `data = np.array([[20, 129],[28, 96], [7, 82], [17, 70], ...])` but I don't recommend doing that.

Comment: I tried with a small sample with np.array() and effectively I got an error : "IndexError: index 46 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 46"
https://trinket.io/embed/python3/a5bd54189b
I will try with loadtxt and a csv

Comment: @gnozer44 The link you gave doesn't have any python code

Comment: My bad https://trinket.io/python3/1995fc1e95

Comment: @gnozer44 my code starts with `n_items_total, k_items_solution, max_weight = 100, 5, 100`. Notice how `n_items_total = 100`. In your code there are only 46 elements in the array. So `n_items_total` should be 46

Comment: @gnozer44 after line `data = ...` you can add a line `n_items_total = len(data)` or equivalently `n_items_total = data.shape[0]` so that `n_items_total` is adjusted automatically to the number of items.

Answer (score 2):

Knapsack problems are hard to tackle with a plain vanilla Google Sheets formula, because storing intermediate results gets complicated, and because recursion is a bit tricky to implement unless you create a named function. You may want to implement Stef's solution as a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions), or if the 30-second runtime limit is not sufficient to process your dataset, as a regular function you start manually through a button or menu item.

Nevertheless, here's a simple illustration of one approach with a plain vanilla formula that takes advantage of the characteristics of the sample data you show:

```
=lambda( 
  weightedData, 
  query( 
    { 
      weightedData, 
      scan( 
        0, index(weightedData, 0, 2), 
        lambda( 
          acc, curr, 
          acc + n(curr) 
        ) 
      ) 
    }, 
    "select Col1, Col2, Col3 
     where Col4 <= 100 
     order by Col3 desc", 0 
  ) 
)( 
  sort( 
    A2:C, 
    C2:C / B2:B, 
    false 
  )
)
```

You can cap the number of elements to 5 by adding `limit 5` in the `query()` statement, but that will simply omit elements rather than recompute with n=5. Please understand that the results will not be optimal — this is for illustration only.

Comment: Yes exactly, I'm currently trying to implement Stef algorithm in a custom function but I can't make it work actually